# Is there a way I could loop through object of many parameters in Op.op sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am setting up a search API, which is to search for; id, type, originCity, destinationCity, departureDate, reason, accommodation, approvalStatus... and the list might increase later

```
const options = {
        id,
        type,
        originCity,
        destinationCity,
        departureDate,
        reason,
        accommodation,
        boolApprovalStatus
      };
```

I am using sequelize `Op` operator, I want my code to be reusable, I don't like to dump all these parameters into the sequelize `Op.op` operator.

`{ where:{ [Op.or]: [{id}, {type}, {originCity}, {destinationCity}, {departureDate}, {reason}, {accommodation}, {approvalStatus}] } }`

I have tried to use the `Object.value(options)` method which did not return any result, and kept my server running without error, until timeout

This is my code below

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
import Request from '../database/models/request';

/**
   * @param {object} options query option
   * @param {object} Request model /table
   * @returns {Promise} Promise resolved or rejected
   * @description get all rows where option matches
   */
  findRequest(options) {
    return Request.findAll({ where: { [Op.or]: Object.values(options) } });
  },
};
```

```
import DbServices from '../services/dbServices';
const { findRequest } = DbServices;

/**
 * search requested trip and approval trip controller
 * @param {Object} req - server request
 * @param {Object} res - server response
 * @returns {Object} - custom response
 */
const searchRequest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      id, type, originCity, destinationCity, departureDate, reason, accommodation, approvalStatus
    } = req.params;

    if (id || type || originCity || destinationCity || departureDate || reason || accommodation
      || approvalStatus || approvalStatus) {
      const boolApprovalStatus = JSON.parse(approvalStatus);

      const options = {
        id,
        type,
        originCity,
        destinationCity,
        departureDate,
        reason,
        accommodation,
        boolApprovalStatus
      };

      const searchResult = await findRequest(options);
      if (searchResult.length <= 0) return response(res, 404, 'error', { message: messages.noResult });
      return response(res, 201, 'success', searchResult);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return response(res, 400, 'error', { message: messages.error });
  }
};

export default {
  requestTrip,
  searchRequest
};
```

Comment: `{ where: { [Op.or]: Object.values(options) }` where are the attributes in the query?

Comment: Have you consoled the value `options` what are you sending to that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply:

```
//converting properties of object into an array of small objects
    const arrayOptions = Object.entries(options).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));

//findRequest function       
 findRequest(options) {
            return Request.findAll({ where: { [Op.or]: arrayOptions } });
          },
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, but the problem now is that I have already destructured ```const {
      id, type, originCity, destinationCity, departureDate, reason, accommodation, approvalStatus
    } = req.params;``` so my object looks like this ```const options = {
        id,
        type,
        originCity,
        destinationCity,
        departureDate,
        reason,
        accommodation,
        boolApprovalStatus
      };
```

Comment: Is that the solution that you are looking for ? If you have already destructured just use the req.body the object is intact there.

Comment: Okay, I am getting the value from req.params

Comment: You have also to understand how destructing work. option is an object like:
// option = {id:1,  type: 'x', ...} the value pair is still there.

Comment: @KazeemOluwatobiOdutola Also it shows appreciation if the answer helps you to solve your problem to upvote and mark as resolved. Is how we work here.

Comment: thanks @iwaduarte it works, I have another question, can I go ahead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rewrite a code you just need to send a query along with the parameters. There will be only on function who will run the query. As you are sending values to the function you need to make whole query along with those values. I hope this will solve your query. You can get more help from [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#where)